# MatLab cells date format conversion

Tags: matlab, date, format, cell

I have a lot of dates in MatLab (over 2 millions). Al these dates are in a cell array in `'yyyymmdd'` format, and I want to convert them to `'yyyy-mm-dd'` format and put this result in a cell array (not in a char matrix).

I know that I can use

```
temp = datestr(datenum(datesArray,'yyyymmdd'),'yyyy-mm-dd'),
```

and then use

```
mat2cell(temp, ones(1,n),10),
```

where `n` is the number of rows of `datesArray` (in this case approximately 2 millions) in order to get my result, but this approach is very slow.

So, I want to know a different way to do that.

Regards.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a really cool solution!

Comment: Why do you still have date in cellstring format and not as serial dates, that is the question!?

Comment: Because these dates are imported from a txt file of an external system.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid for loops by using `cellfun`, let's say your date cell array is

```
dates = {'20120101', '20120102', '20120103'}
```

You can then convert them to your format as

```
cellfun(@(x)[x(1:4),'-',x(5:6),'-',x(7:8)], dates, 'Uniform', false)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This solutions Works fine and as fast as expected.

Comment: A `cellfun()` is a concealed loop and 99% of the case slower than an explicit one.

Answer (score 0):

If your date format is always "yyyymmdd" and it's in a linear cell array called `datesArray`, you could maybe do it by accessing the strings in `datesArray` and transforming them by inserting hyphens and concatenating the string.

```
for i=1:length(datesArray)
newDatesArray{i} = [datesArray{i}(1:4), '-', datesArray{i}(5:6), '-', datesArray{i}(7:8)];
end
```

Comment: I will try that, but usually MatLab is not very efficient when we use loops. So, Im thinking in some approach that aviod loops.

Comment: Holy jeebus I made a lot of mistakes. Should be fixed now. Teaches me not to try it out first (what was I thinking?)

Comment: If you want speed, I might actually just recommend switching to a faster language. C, UNIX, or even Python would probably outperform MATLAB for huge arrays. When I switch operating systems again, I could probably find a decent UNIX answer (and check it before I post it :P), but you could also try posting another question with more language tags.

Comment: Sorry @thefourtheye, but the questions was not about other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your dates into serial one and keep them! However, here's a solution:

```
% Create dummy dates (takes 10 seconds on my pc)
tic;d = cellstr(datestr(now-2e5+1:now,'yyyymmdd'));toc

% Convert to char, then concatenate with '-' and back to `cellstr()` (1 sec):
c    = char(d);
dash = repmat('-',2e5,1);
c    = cellstr([c(:,1:4) dash c(:,5:6) dash c(:,7:8)]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case the initial dates are not in a cell array.

Comment: Which case? `d` is a cell array of string dates.

Answer (score 0):

So here my solution, which i think is quite nice!

```
dates = {'20120101', '20120102', '20120103'}
```

And you can convert using this :

```
cellfun(@(x)regexprep(num2str(x), '(?<=\d{4})\d{2}', '-$0'),dates,'Uniform',false)
```

The answer is similar to radarhead, but it uses the `regexprep` function instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In fact, I try
regexprep(date, '(?<=\d{4})\d{2}', '-$0')

and also Works fine :)